# Point sub domain to root AND redirect main domain

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have
'website.com' and 'newwebsite.com', both on LAMP environment.

I need 
website.com redirecting to newwebsite.com
AND 
old.website.com pointing to root of website.com

I have full control of both hosting and DNS records.
I can't figure out the best solution without creating a loop !

Comment: You don't say what webserver are you using. Is it HTTP 301 redirect is what you want or should website.com should resolve to newwebsite.com ?

Comment: Thank you Ajay for pointing that out, I made the edit.
I'm not sure about HTTP Redirect vs DNS registration - that's part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two choices here: redirects, or DNS records. If you do it with redirects it means the user will see that they have been forwarded elsewhere. If you use DNS, the user will not be aware of the deprecation of the old websites.

For this reason, I would use HTTP redirects for this task.

If you wanted to go the DNS route then simply have an A record for newwebsite.com and CNAMES for the others that point to it.